# Is there a way to auto print out attachments that come from a specific email address?

Tags: vba, email, printing, outlook, email-attachments

I'm trying to create a way to auto print attachments when outlook detects that the email was sent from a specific person in Outlook. I am trying to make it so that when this email comes through, no buttons have to be pressed and the attachments in that email will be sent to the printer.

I've tried using ChatGPT to give me a solution for this. I've used a combination of VBA code within outlook and outlook rules to try and accomplish this. I think this may be the way to attack this, but I feel I have the incorrect VBA code.

There is a way to print using strictly Outlook rules, but this just prints the body of the email and not the attachments. But I have confirmed this works so I don't believe it is an issue with the printer or the Outlook Rules I have created.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Could you be more specific?

Comment: This is the code I used in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save attached files and only then you can run a command (Windows API) to print the file, for example, take a look at the following sample code:

```
' use  Declare PtrSafe Function with 64-bit Outlook
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
  "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Folder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set Items = Folder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    PrintAttachments Item
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintAttachments(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim colAtts As Outlook.Attachments
  Dim oAtt As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim sDirectory As String
  Dim sFileType As String

  sDirectory = "D:\Attachments\"

  Set colAtts = oMail.Attachments

  If colAtts.Count Then
    For Each oAtt In colAtts

      ' This code looks at the last 4 characters in a filename
      sFileType = LCase$(right$(oAtt.FileName, 4))

      Select Case sFileType

      ' Add additional file types below
      Case ".xls", ".doc", "docx"

        sFile = sDirectory  & oAtt.FileName
        oAtt.SaveAsFile sFile
        ShellExecute 0, "print", sFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0
      End Select
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Also you may consider handling the `NewMailEx` event of the Application instead of `ItemAdd` event used in the sample code. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection string to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item.